# Counting the number of columns in a mysql table not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have been looking on the forum for a means by which to count the number of columns in mysql table.

I had thought I had found the answer however it doesn't seem to be working. A snippet of my query is below:

```
$count = queryMysql("SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='" . $dbname . "' AND table_name='" . $table . "'");
```

`$dname` contains the name of my database and `$table` is passed into my function as an argument and is the name of the table.

when I `echo $count` it simple prints `Resource id#5`

Comment: You need to fetch the data from the query. `fetch_object()` or `fetch_array()`, but it'll depend what you're using in terms of MySQL interface functions.

Answer (score 2):

Standard mysql libraries' `query()` functions return a result HANDLE, even if the query would only ever return a single field and/or row. You need to FETCH a row from that handle, e.g.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['count'];
```

In this code, if you did `echo $row`, you'd get your output of `Resource id#xxx` because it's NOT the value that was selected - it's the result handle of what you can FETCH that value from.

Answer (score 1):

After executing the query you need to fetch the data returned from it. Please have a look at this example:

```
        $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='" . $dbname . "' AND table_name='" . $table . "'";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, after reading all of these answers i've got it sorted. Thanks again from a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a custom function queryMysql() which doesn't handle the output of the count right, alter it to:

```
$count = queryMysql("SELECT count(*) AS columnCount 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema='" . $dbname . "' 
    AND table_name='" . $table . "'");
```

Note how I select it `as columnCount` so it is named properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='" . $dbname . "' AND table_name='" . $table . "'");
    $nums = mysql_num_rows($count);
    for($i=0; $i < $nums; $i++;){
    $result = mysql_result($count,$i,"count");
    echo $table." : ".$result;
    }
```